# What does "no recourse short of" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective:

> **Class 4: Functions that call thread-unsafe functions.** If a function f calls a thread- unsafe function g, is f thread-unsafe? It depends.
> If g is a class 2 function that relies on state across multiple
> invocations, then f is also thread- unsafe and there is **no recourse
> short of** rewriting g. However, if g is a class 1 or class 3
> function, then f can still be thread-safe if you protect the call site
> and any resulting shared data with a mutex. We see a good example of
> this in Figure 12.38, where we use lock-and-copy to write a
> thread-safe function that calls a thread-unsafe function.

What does "no recourse short of" mean? I know recourse means a source of help. but I don't know what that sentence means.

Thanks.

Comment: A recourse is a choice, and short of means less than (before you reach X). So, no options besides rewriting the g function. *You give me anything short of the full rent, and I will evict you*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Recourse = using something or someone as a way of getting help, especially in a difficult or dangerous situation
>
> Cambridge dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recourse

For example: “We were trapped by the tide; we had to recourse to a boat to escape.”

*Recourse* is being used in the same way in your text. There is no way of removing the danger or improving the situation other than rewriting. The use of “*short of*” says that minor changes such as a partial rewrite, or changing some parameters, will not be enough; you must recourse to a complete rewrite of the function g.